# how to Make small ticker screen Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, ticker

I want to customize very first MainScreen of my Blackberry application as like small ticker screen. My aim is that the first MainScreen should be of size 320width,100height so when user launches the application then he will just see screen of size 320width and 100height (0,200,320,100) while remaining screen will be transparent and user will see other applications through transparent screen.

Answer (score 0):

The best you could do is take a [screenshot](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Display.html#screenshot%28net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap%29) with your app backgrounded, to capture what would be underneath.  Then draw the 320x100 UI on top of that screenshot.  This has the visual effect you want, but if the underlying screens try to draw any update, that update will not be reflected in your UI.

Comment: :( i want something like BreakNews app ,very well-know blackberry app. http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/41242?lang=en

Comment: Mr. Michael Donohue, can you tell me briefly about ticker screen Blackberry? Please or provide any link to understand for that;

Comment: @AliShaik  i want to develop same app screen as in http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/screenshots/41242?lang=en

Comment: I have used UiApplication.getUIApplication().pushGlobalScreen(new myScreen(),1,true);  due to this code my ticker screen is visible to me on blackberry home screen but i was unable to get other events like user cannot open blackberry messages,call etc, all the time my ticker screen get focus although i can see blackberry home screen but was unabale to interact with them.